# How to break a Aggregation,when i got expected result at camel split?

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregation

// extends CamelTestSupport

```
@Produce
private ProducerTemplate template;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:out")
private MockEndpoint mock;

@Test
public void testSplitAggregateConvertOrder(){
    List<InOrder> inOrderList = new ArrayList<InOrder>();

    InOrder inOrder1 = new InOrder();
    inOrder1.setId("1");
    inOrderList.add(inOrder1);

    InOrder inOrder2 = new InOrder();
    inOrder2.setId("2");
    inOrderList.add(inOrder2);

    InOrder inOrder3 = new InOrder();
    inOrder3.setId("3");
    inOrderList.add(inOrder3);

    template.sendBody("direct:start", inOrderList);

    Exchange outList = mock.getReceivedExchanges().get(0);
    List<OutOrder> outOrderList = outList.getIn().getBody(List.class);
    for(OutOrder outOrder : outOrderList){
        System.out.println("####### mockResult id : "+outOrder.getId());
    }
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

             context.getTypeConverterRegistry().addTypeConverter(OutOrder.class, InOrder.class, new MyOrderTypeConverter());

            from("direct:start")
            .split(body(), new AggregationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                    if (oldExchange == null) {
                        List<OutOrder> orders = new ArrayList<OutOrder>();
                        OutOrder newOrder = newExchange.getIn().getBody(OutOrder.class);
                        orders.add(newOrder);
                        newExchange.getIn().setBody(orders);
                        return newExchange;
                    }
                    List<OutOrder> orders = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                    OutOrder newOutOrder = newExchange.getIn().getBody(OutOrder.class);
                    orders.add(newOutOrder);
                    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(orders);
                    return oldExchange;
                }
            })
            .convertBodyTo(OutOrder.class)
            .end()  //splitter ends here and the exchange body  is now List<OutOrder>
            .to("mock:out");
        }
    };
}

private static class MyOrderTypeConverter extends TypeConverterSupport {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value) {
        // converter from inorder to outorder bean
        OutOrder order = new OutOrder();
        order.setId(Integer.parseInt(((InOrder) value).getId()));
        return (T) order;
    }
}

private static class OutOrder {
    private int id;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

private static class InOrder {
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I just need the list size fixed,like {1,2}, but result were all returned ,the result was {1,2,3}.

I just want when the result size equals 2, break the Aggregation. Does any body help me?

Answer (score 0):

The splitter with the aggregation strategy will always aggregate all the splitted sub messages. So if there is 3 sub messages, you get 3 aggregations. But because its java code, you can just keep track of that yourself and if you already have aggregated 2 messages, then you can just ignore the 3rd when its called.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but the function MyOrderTypeConverter.convertTo actually need more than one minute at a time. so in my mind, if i got the correct result then break immediately.Maybe there have other suggestion to resolve it ?